# how to wait for startActivityForResult to continue next line in android java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

my code is below,
whenever salesmanName value is empty i am not getting Login success Log.
how to get that. after getting result i want to execute next line.

```
    if(salesmanName=="" ||salesmanName==null) {

        Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                com.example.mysouq.LoginActivity.class);

        startActivityForResult(intent1,LOGIN);
    }
    Log.e("Login success",salesmanName);
```

Comment: When are you calling this?

Comment: OnCreate method

Answer (score 1):

Do not use == for Strings

```
String var = new String("");
""==var => false
```

use equals:

```
"".equals(var)
```

also
salesmanName will be empty in you last line

Comment: this solves the issue partially, but OP will have to implement onActivityResult for this to make sense

Comment: you are right @a_local_nobody but i can only talk about the visible =)

Comment: @Rkernala - how to get last line salesman name . Is there any way ?

Comment: @hashimfajar if salsmaneName is empty or null... no.. no way.